# I need an immutable key-value structure that retains insertion order

Tags: java, guava, immutability, linkedhashmap

I want to find something like `ImmutableLinkedHashMap<>` in Guava library.
I need to use an immutable key-value data structure with an insertion order. 
So, what should I use?

Comment: See [Package com.google.common.collect Description](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/package-summary.html#package_description) and [ImmutableCollectionsExplained on Guava wiki](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Collections ImmutableMap iteration order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810738/google-collections-immutablemap-iteration-order)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I am not sure I am understanding exactly what you are after, but if it is a really immutable `Map`, you mght want to look at [`ImmutableMap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html)

As mentioned in the doc:

> An immutable, hash-based `Map` with reliable user-specified iteration order. Does not permit null keys or values.
>
> Unlike `Collections.unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map<? extends K, ? extends V>)`, which is a view of a separate map which can still change, an instance of `ImmutableMap` contains its own data and will never change. `ImmutableMap` is convenient for `public static final` maps ("constant maps") and also lets you easily make a "defensive copy" of a map provided to your class by a caller

E.g, you could use it in a similar fashion:

```
Map<Integer, String> m = ImmutableMap.of(5,"Five",6,"Six",7,"Seven");
```

Hope this is what you were after.

Comment: Yes I was just going to say that as well.  `ImmutableMap` looks like it should work.

Comment: The issue with this is that `ImmutableSortedMap` extends `ImmutableMap`, so if you have clients of this method, you can't enforce insertion order maintenance by types.

Answer (score 10):

First create a `LinkedHashMap` and then use [`ImmutableMap.copyOf(linkedHashMap)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html#copyOf%28java.util.Map%29) to create an immutable copy which will have the same ordering as the original map.